# Can you count a particular class with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-counter

Lets say I have a simple list like so:

```
<ol>
    <li class="count">one</li>
    <li class="count">two</li>
    <li class="count">three</li>
    <li class="count">four</li>
    <li>blabla</li>
    <li class="count">five</li>
    <li class="count">six</li>
    <li>blabla</li>
    <li class="count">seven</li>
</ol>
```

Now I only want to number list items with the class 'count'

So If I add the CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

and then remove the list-style-type for list items without the class:

```
li:not(.count) {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

I get this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/03bu5sct/5/)**

```css
li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
li:not(.count) {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="count">one</li>
  <li class="count">two</li>
  <li class="count">three</li>
  <li class="count">four</li>
  <li>blabla</li>
  <li class="count">five</li>
  <li class="count">six</li>
  <li>blabla</li>
  <li class="count">seven</li>
</ol>
```

The obvious problem here is that the list items without the class are also 'counted' here, just not shown.

So in the above example, the list should be numbered to 7 - with the numbering skipping the list items without the class.
Can this be done with CSS?

Comment: To be pedantic: if you want numbers for your list items then this might best be represented as an ordered list `<ol>`

Comment: @nickgrim - thanks for pointing that out - I edited the question to use an ordered list `<ol>`

Answer (score 34):

This can be done with [CSS-counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters)

If I set `display:none` on the generated content with the counter, the counter skips over it, and continues to the next item!

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/em13s2qL/8/)**

(**Edit:** Or, alternatively - as others have pointed out - we could increment the counter only on the elements with the particular class - [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/em13s2qL/9/))

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: count;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
li:before {
  content: counter(count)".";
  counter-increment: count;
}
li:not(.count) {
  padding-left: 13px;
}
li:not(.count):before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="count">one</li>
  <li class="count">two</li>
  <li class="count">three</li>
  <li class="count">four</li>
  <li>blabla</li>
  <li class="count">five</li>
  <li class="count">six</li>
  <li>blabla</li>
  <li class="count">seven</li>
</ol>
```

So actually, with counters, not only can we count classes, we can also count any selector combination.

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/becurymk/2/) for proof of concept:

```css
html {
  counter-reset: divs;
}
body {
  counter-reset: paragraphs;
  position: relative;
}
div {
  counter-increment: divs;
}
.wpr {
  counter-reset: count-me;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.container .count-me {
  counter-increment: count-me;
}
.container p {
  counter-increment: paragraphs;
}
.wpr:after {
  content: "Number of count-me classes in container:" counter(count-me);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
}
.container:after {
  content: "Number of paragraphs:" counter(paragraphs);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
}
body:after {
  content: "Number of divs:" counter(divs);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">div1
  <div class="container">div2
    <div>div3
      <span class="count-me">count-me</span>
    </div>
    <div>div4
      <span class="count-me">count-me</span>
      <p>I"m a paragragh</p>
    </div>
    <div>div5
      <p>I"m a paragragh</p>
    </div>
    <div>div6
      <span class="count-me">count-me</span>
    </div>
    <div>div7
      <span class="count-me">count-me</span>
      <p>I"m a paragragh</p>
    </div>
    <div>div8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you may set the class name to `nocount` instead and assign it to the items without a counter. `li:before` would have the counter declaration and `li.nocount:before` the `display:none` declaration.

Bonus points: make the UL position relative and the counter absolute: http://jsfiddle.net/em13s2qL/6/

Comment: I really don't like to use the `:not()` selector. Old browsers will choke on that piece of css. Try this one instead: http://jsfiddle.net/q7zLz3nz/ which is much more compatible and oldie-friendly.

Answer (score 9):

Giving `display: block` to the li elements without `.count` class is also working.

```
ul {
    list-style-type:decimal;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
li:not(.count) {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/em13s2qL/2/)**

For older browsers:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:decimal;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
li {
    display: block;
}
li.count {
    display: list-item;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/em13s2qL/3/)

Another way, if you are planning to change the display state of all `li` elements, use `:after`/`:before` pseudo classes with display as list-item.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/em13s2qL/5/)**

Comment: Hey @Mr_Green, I decided to award you a bounty since your solution worked well too :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML to set the value of a list item specifically:

```
<ul>
    <li class="count">one</li>
    <li class="count">two</li>
    <li class="count">three</li>
    <li class="count">four</li>
    <li>blabla</li>
    <li value="5" class="count">five</li>
    <li class="count">six</li>
    <li>blabla</li>
    <li value="7" class="count">seven</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/03bu5sct/1/

You may also want to look at CSS3 counters if you want a pure CSS solution.

Comment: How about this css instead: `li.count{list-style-type: decimal;}li{list-style-type: none;}`?

Answer (score 3):

The [counters section in CSS 2.1 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters) contains various examples of how to implement your custom counter. Here is a very simple example where you:

1. Define a counter variable
2. Increment it for specific elements (in your case it would be `.count` elements)
3. Display it inside pseudo elements

```css
.custom-counter {
  /* define a counter variable */
  counter-reset: clumsycount 0;
  /* style */
  list-style-type: none;
}
.custom-counter .count {
  /* increment the counter variable */
  counter-increment: clumsycount 1;
  /* style */
  position: relative;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
.custom-counter .count:before {
  /* display the counter variable */
  content: counter(clumsycount) ".";
  /* style */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  padding-right: .25em;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<ul class="custom-counter">
  <li class="count">one</li>
  <li class="count">two</li>
  <li class="count">three</li>
  <li class="count">four</li>
  <li>blabla</li>
  <li class="count">five</li>
  <li class="count">six</li>
  <li>blabla</li>
  <li class="count">seven</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
li {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}

li:not(.count) {
      -webkit-appearance: textfield;
      -moz-appearance: textfield;
      appearance: textfield;
}
```

this is a simple hack http://jsfiddle.net/9w9vkcf3/1/

> The `appearance` property is used to display an element using a platform-native styling based on the users' operating system's theme. [source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/)

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use [**CSS counters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) and apply it using pseudo-element [**:before**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) taking advance of [**content**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content) property with counter,

> Counters may be specified with two different functions: 'counter()' or
>   'counters()'. The former has two forms: 'counter(name)' or
>   'counter(name, style)'. The generated text is the value of the
>   innermost counter of the given name in scope at this pseudo-element;
>   it is formatted in the indicated style ('decimal' by default). The
>   latter function also has two forms: 'counters(name, string)' or
>   'counters(name, string, style)'. The generated text is the value of
>   all counters with the given name in scope at this pseudo-element, from
>   outermost to innermost separated by the specified string. The counters
>   are rendered in the indicated style ('decimal' by default). See the
>   section on automatic counters and numbering for more information. The
>   name must not be 'none', 'inherit' or 'initial'. Such a name causes
>   the declaration to be ignored.

only in `li` elements with class `count`:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;/* Set the section counter to 0 */
}
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li.count::before {
  counter-increment: section;/* Increment the section counter*/
  content: counter(section)". ";/* Display the counter */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="count">one</li>
  <li class="count">two</li>
  <li class="count">three</li>
  <li class="count">four</li>
  <li>blabla</li>
  <li class="count">five</li>
  <li class="count">six</li>
  <li>blabla</li>
  <li class="count">seven</li>
</ol>
```

**References**

[counter-increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment)

[counter-reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/Cheese1991/qnmhvvxj/

HTML:

```html
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li class="skip">Skip</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
ul {
    counter-reset:yourCounter;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li:not(.skip) {
    counter-increment:yourCounter;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li:not(.skip):before {
    content:counter(yourCounter) ". ";
}
ul li.skip:before {
    content:"\a0\a0\a0";
}
```

I hope this will help you