# Get index of class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the index of an element in a class. For example if I have a class called `myClass` with 5 elements, and the fourth element has an id of `fourth`, I want to get the index number of `#fourth` from the class.

I tried using `indexOf` like this:

```
var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var fourth = document.getElementById('fourth');

console.log(myClass.indexOf(fourth));
```

But I get an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: myClass.indexOf is not a function

#### JSFiddle

**Code Snippet**

```js
var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var fourth = document.getElementById('fourth');

console.log(myClass.indexOf(fourth));
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass" id="fourth"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

I then tried creating my own function that gets the index from the class:

```
function indexInClass(node) {
    var className = node.className;
    var num = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < className.length; i++) {
        if (className[i] === node) {
            return num;
        }
        num++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

But I get undefined when I use it.

How can I get the index of the class?

#### JSFiddle

**Code Snippet**

```js
var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var fourth = document.getElementById('fourth');

function indexInClass(node) {
  var className = node.className;
  var num = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < className.length; i++) {
    if (className[i] === node) {
      return num;
    }
    num++;
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(myClass[indexInClass(fourth)]);
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass" id="fourth"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean via "the index number"? You are using `indexOf` on a DOM node...

Comment: @Raffaele, `myClass` is a collection of DOM nodes, not an individual DOM node.

Comment: Not sure, but you might need iterate over myClass and use the .getattribute() to check if the current element has an attribute of 'id'

Comment: I know that this is a Javascript question, but just in case anyone's interested you can do something like this **with CSS using counters** [(Codepen demo)](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/Rrxozq). Of course, you would only be able to display the result, not access it in javascript. (In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26841866/703717) I showed an example for proof of concept)

Comment: @Danield Wow! I did not know that! CSS is more powerful than I thought! `Ani rotzeh lishol otcha shala. Ata yachol` email me? My email is on my stackoverflow profile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an HTML collection, not an array, thus you cannon use `indexOf` on it.

Iterating over the elements is the way to go, but the problem with your custom function was this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < className.length; i++) {
```

You were iterating over `className`, which is a string containing your `node`'s class name, while instead you should be iterating over your element collection `myClass`.

Here's your custom function fixed:

```js
var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var fourth = document.getElementById('fourth');

function indexInClass(node) {
  var className = node.className;
  var num = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myClass.length; i++) {
    if (myClass[i] === node) {
      return num;
    }
    num++;
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(myClass[indexInClass(fourth)]);
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass" id="fourth"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

---

### UPDATE

> Thanks for the answer! I want to create a function that I can use anywhere, meaning, not specific to myClass. How can I achieve that?

Here's a sligthly optimized version of your function:

```js
function indexInClass(collection, node) {
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if (collection[i] === node)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var fourth = document.getElementById('fourth');

alert("The ID is: " + indexInClass(myClass, fourth));
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass" id="fourth"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

---

### UPDATE 2

> Is there a way to do it without the collection argument? For example, is there a way to get the class from the id?

```js
function indexInClass(node) {
  var collection = document.getElementsByClassName(node.className);
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if (collection[i] === node)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

var fourth = document.getElementById('fourth');

alert("The ID is: " + indexInClass(fourth));
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass" id="fourth"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Be careful with `.className` because it will work properly if the node has one class. If you expect more, you'd need to extract the common one, either from `className` or `classList`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I want to create a function that I can use anywhere, meaning, not specific to `myClass`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You're welcome! Well, you can extend it by adding one more parameter to it - the class name or the HTML collection so that you can call your function like this for example: `indexInClass('myClassName', element);` Does that make sense?

Comment: What would I replace `myClass.lenght` and `myclass[i]` with?

Comment: You'd replace it with the proper function argument. See if my update helps.

Comment: @Jessica, does it make sense? We're basically just passing in the collection of elements and a specific element we're looking for inside that collection, and the function returns its index.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the `collection` argument? For example, is there  a way to get the class from the id?

Comment: You mean like `document.getElementById('fourth').className`? You can do that inside the function and create the collection before the loop. For example: `var collection = document.getElementsByClassName(node.className);` (see the update)

Answer (score 3):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which does not have the `indexOf` array methods.

If you have access to [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), then the simple solution is to use it to convert the collection to an array and call `indexOf`:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('myClass'))
    .indexOf(fourth); //3
```

If you can't use `Array.from`, then [`Array.prototype.slice.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) should work:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('myClass'))
    .indexOf(fourth); //3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom function has the right idea, you're just iterating over the wrong variable. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdcq8ef0/)

```
var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var fourth = document.getElementById('fourth');

function indexInClass(node) {
    var className = node.className;
    var num = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < myClass.length; i++) {
        if (myClass[i] === node) {
            return num;
        }
        num++;
    }
    return -1;
}

console.log(indexInClass(fourth));
```