# Catching className number in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

It's easy to change class 'day' with addEventListener if I specify it with day[2], day[3] etc.

I don't really want to write all that code for each of them, how could I catch the class' order number "day[?]" when it's clicked, so I could use it in changeDate().

Parts of current code:

```js
var day = document.getElementsByClassName("day");

day[2].addEventListener("click", changeDate);

function changeDate() {
  console.log("hit");
}
```

```html
<li class="day">1</li>
<li class="day">2</li>
<li class="day">3</li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910042/get-index-of-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code using standard javascript to find and attach click event handlers to all `.day` HTML elements.

```html
<body>
<li class="day">1</li>
<li class="day">2</li>
<li class="day">3</li>
...
</body>

<script>
var dayArray = [];

window.onload = function(){

  dayArray = document.getElementsByClassName("day");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < dayArray.length; i++) {
    dayArray[i].addEventListener('click', changeDate, false);
  }

};

function changeDate(evt){
   console.log(this); // Here 'this' refers to the clicked HTML element
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the `changeData()` function, you are able to access to `this`. It's the associated `<li>` (which were clicked), so use `this.innerHTML` to get the number of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Get all of the classes and loop through them to add listeners, like this:

```
var days = document.getElementsByClassName('day');
for(var i = 0; i < days.length; i++){
    days[i].addEventListener('click', changeDate);
}
```

EDIT: sorry, missed the last line: Your change date function can then include the following:

```
function changeDate(){
     var day = this.textContent;
};
```

Now the `day` variable in the text inside the element that was clicked.

Comment: This doesn't address the question: *how could I catch the class' order number "day[?]" when it's clicked, so I could use it in changeDate()*

Answer (score -2):

Addition to @fauxserious answer you could try this:

```
var days = document.getElementsByClassName('day');
for(var i = 0; i < days.length; i++){
    days[i].addEventListener('click', changeDate);
}

function changeDate(){
   console.log('Clicked day ' + this.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: No. That will call `changeDate` **immediately** and assign its return value as the event listener (since that return value is `undefined` with your code, it won't attach an event listener at all).